# Icon on left and Text on right HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I think this may sound pretty simple, but still I can not get it to work.

My design has different icons of same size and height and I need to display them one below another and at the same time I need to give a small description about the icon on the right side for every icon.

The text for every icon on the right side consists of two lines, the first line in bold(header) and the second line normal(description). The padding and  margin is my call. But I need to display them in that way in my content.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, just paste the actual code ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply left align your image and then devide 2 lines of your text with line break

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="float:left;" />
<strong>Header</strong><br />
<span>description</span>
```

Comment: dont use strong, unless you mean that phrase strongly.

Comment: @Raaks Glad this example worked for you, but please do try to avoid using `<em>` and `<strong>` unless you are intending to emphasis and strongly emphasis that phrase respectively.

Answer (score 1):

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUqWv/2/) should set you in the right direction.

It basically floats both the `<img>` and `<p>`

Its not a finished artical, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/8hPF8/)

Basically there is a container `div` with an unordered list inside it, each list item has a background image to the left and text to the right, no floats are used.